# Java to JavaScript (Encryption related)

Tags: java, javascript, hash, md5, base64

I'm having difficulties to get the same string in Javascript and I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong...

Java code:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

private static String getBase64Code(String input) throws 
         UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    String base64 = "";

    byte[] txt = input.getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] text = new byte[txt.length+3];

    text[0] = (byte)239;
    text[1] = (byte)187;
    text[2] = (byte)191;

    for(int i=0; i<txt.length; i++)
       text[i+3] = txt[i];

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(text);
    byte digest[] = md.digest();

    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    base64 = encoder.encode(digest);

    return base64;
 }
```

I'm trying this using [Paul's MD5 script](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/scripts.html) as well [Farhadi Base 64 Encode script](http://farhadi.ir/works/base64)

but my tests fail completely :(

my code:

```
function CalculateCredentialsSecret(type, user, pwd) {

var days = days_between(new Date(), new Date(2000, 1, 1));
var str = type.toUpperCase() + user.toUpperCase() + pwd.toUpperCase() + days;
    var padding_data = String.fromCharCode(239) + 
                       String.fromCharCode(187) + 
                       String.fromCharCode(191);

var md5 = hex_md5(padding_data + str);
var b64 = base64Encode(md5);

return encodeURIComponent(b64);
}
```

Does anyone know how can I convert **this** Java method into a Javascript one?

**Thank you**

---

Tests (for today (*29-09-2010*), **3740 days** after January 1st, 2000)

```
var secret = CalculateCredentialsSecret('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC');

// secret SHOULD be: S3GYAfGWlmrhuoNsIJF94w==
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct code is

```
function CalculateCredentialsSecret(type, user, pwd) {

var days = days_between(new Date(), new Date(2000, 1, 1)) + 30;
var str = type.toUpperCase() + user.toUpperCase() + pwd.toUpperCase() + days;

var padding_data = String.fromCharCode(239, 187, 191);

var md5 = rstr_md5(padding_data+str);
var b64 = base64Encode(md5);

return encodeURIComponent(b64);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/ <-- get Md5 function from there (first page on google for 'javascript md5')
http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html <-- get base64 en/de code (googled 'javascript base64 encode')

```
function getBase64Code(input)
{
  base64 = "";
  txt = input
  text = [];
  text[0] = (byte)239; // These three lines I am stuck on
  text[1] = (byte)187; // These three lines I am stuck on
  text[2] = (byte)191; // These three lines I am stuck on

  for(int i=0; i<txt.length; i++)
  {
    text[i+3] = txt[i];
  }
  digest = hex_md5(text);
  base64 = Base64(digest);
  return base64;
}
```

Just realised... if all you want to do is endocde in base64 for transporting the data, look at the second link. may do what you want as it is.

**UPDATE:**

you should be able to do something like this then, assume those extra bytes could replaced a three characters.

```
encoded = Base64.encode(hexmd5(padding_data + data));
```

Comment: (1.) in javascript there is no type byte 
(2.) those 3 lines is to add 3 Byte values to the string to be encrypted/encoded.

Comment: I want to transport data, but I want to apply MD5 encrytation on the passed string first

Comment: @balexandre I know what they do, I just don't know how to do the do the equivalent in JS.